# When I tried JSON Parsing in android using Asynchronous HTTP client,it doesnot work

Tags: android

Can you please correct  me if I am wrong.Please find the below code for The belowcode is the MainActivity.java.I tried to get the value from the link through AsynchronousHTTPClient.It doesnot show the any error and output

```
package com.asynchro.sowmy.asynchrono;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    AsyncHttpClient client;
    ListView list;
    JSONObject object;
    JSONArray array;
    ArrayList names;
    ArrayList statess;
    String url="http://sicsglobal.co.in/agroapp/Json/AllFarmers.aspx";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.LstView);
        names=new ArrayList();
        statess=new ArrayList();
        client.get(url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                System.out.println(responseBody);
                try{
                    object=new JSONObject();
                    String a=object.optString("AllFarmers");
                    array=new JSONArray();
                    for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
                        obj=obj.getJSONObject(String.valueOf(i));
                        String name=obj.getString("Name");
                        String state=obj.getString("State");
                        names.add(name);
                        statess.add(state);
                        ArrayAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,names);
                        list.setAdapter(adapter);

                    }

                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you given INTERNET permission??

Comment: You not get properly, if you get json array in `String a` then you need to pass to json object and you don't do,so you just get JSONArray from you JSON Object and get you all data

Answer (score 0):

try changing this part:

```
 try {
                                    array = json.getJSONArray("name of ur    array");
                                    for (int n = 0; n < array.length(); n++)     {


                                            obj = array.getJSONObject(n);
}
}
```

u need to give the name of the json array...

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.loopj.android.http.RequestHandle
 com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient.get(java.lang.String, com.loopj.android.http.
 ResponseHandlerInterface)' on a null object reference

Comment: did u initialize the json array ??       give    JSONArray array = null;                        before the try statement